# How to apply Google Analytics on Sharepoint-Addin Webpart

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

How to apply Google Analytics on Sharepoint-Addin Webpart. I have implemented Google Analytics in regular aspx pages of dotnet application but dont know how to do the same in Sharepoint-Addin.

Comment: it is Sharepoint Online

Comment: please share code

Answer (score 1):

Assuming its just a MVC app, you would just need to add your snippet into the _Layout.cshtml

The following link will give you an idea of how it works.

http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/layout-view-in-asp.net-mvc

Comment: i did mate. add the snippet to layout.cshtml. please re read, or suggest how i can improve

Comment: James it is an AddIn webpart of sharepoint online

Comment: yes i read that. and there are a number of ways creating them. MVC is one them (and very common). share code to clarify.

Comment: it is sharepoint hosted javascript based Addin

Comment: ah ok fair enough. cant you simply add the javascript inside yours?

Comment: I tried it but did not get analytics results